# JCuda access violation when creating a texture object with the driver API

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, jcuda, cuda-arrays

I have a JCuda project that's encountering an access violation whenever it tries to create a texture object using the driver API. Java HotSpot claims that the error is coming from nvcuda.dll.

The underlying CUarray from which the texture is being created seems to be populated correctly; copying its contents back into a host-side float array results in an array that's identical to the initial host-side data. That means that the error itself has to be something in the texture declaration, right?

Running the code using cuda-memcheck reveals no errors.

Here is the code that's encountering the error:

```
import jcuda.Pointer;
import jcuda.Sizeof;
import jcuda.driver.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();

        float[] hostArray = new float[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        int[] dims = new int[]{2,2,2};

        CUdeviceptr deviceArray = new CUdeviceptr();
        JCudaDriver.cuMemAlloc(deviceArray, hostArray.length * Sizeof.FLOAT);
        JCudaDriver.cuMemcpyHtoD(deviceArray, Pointer.to(hostArray), hostArray.length * Sizeof.FLOAT);

        // initialize the opaque array object to represent the texture's data
        CUarray cuArray = makeCudaArray(dims);

        // populate the opaque array object
        copyDataIntoCudaArray(deviceArray, cuArray, dims);

        JCudaDriver.cuMemFree(deviceArray);

        // create the various descriptors
        CUDA_RESOURCE_DESC resourceDescriptor = makeResourceDescriptor(cuArray);
        CUDA_TEXTURE_DESC textureDescriptor = makeTextureDescriptor();
        CUDA_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC resourceViewDescriptor = makeResourceViewDescriptor(dims);

        CUtexObject texture = new CUtexObject();

        System.out.println("About to hit an access violation:");
        JCudaDriver.cuTexObjectCreate(texture, resourceDescriptor, textureDescriptor, resourceViewDescriptor);
    }

    static void init() {
        JCudaDriver.setExceptionsEnabled(true);
        JCudaDriver.cuInit(0);

        int[] deviceCount = new int[1];
        JCudaDriver.cuDeviceGetCount(deviceCount);

        CUdevice currentDevice = new CUdevice();
        JCudaDriver.cuDeviceGet(currentDevice, 0);

        CUcontext currentContext = new CUcontext();
        JCudaDriver.cuCtxCreate(currentContext, 0, currentDevice);
    }

    static CUarray makeCudaArray(int[] dims) {
        CUarray array = new CUarray();
        CUDA_ARRAY3D_DESCRIPTOR arrayDescriptor = new CUDA_ARRAY3D_DESCRIPTOR();

        arrayDescriptor.Width = dims[0];
        arrayDescriptor.Height = dims[1];
        arrayDescriptor.Depth = dims[2];
        arrayDescriptor.Format = CUarray_format.CU_AD_FORMAT_FLOAT;
        arrayDescriptor.NumChannels = 1;
        arrayDescriptor.Flags = 0;

        JCudaDriver.cuArray3DCreate(array, arrayDescriptor);
        return array;
    }

    static void copyDataIntoCudaArray(CUdeviceptr deviceArray, CUarray array, int[] dims) {
        CUDA_MEMCPY3D copyParams = new CUDA_MEMCPY3D();
        copyParams.srcMemoryType = CUmemorytype.CU_MEMORYTYPE_DEVICE;
        copyParams.srcDevice = deviceArray;
        copyParams.srcXInBytes = 0;
        copyParams.srcY = 0;
        copyParams.srcZ = 0;
        copyParams.srcPitch = (long) dims[0] * Sizeof.FLOAT;
        copyParams.srcHeight = dims[1];
        copyParams.srcLOD = 0;

        copyParams.dstMemoryType = CUmemorytype.CU_MEMORYTYPE_ARRAY;
        copyParams.dstArray = array;
        copyParams.dstXInBytes = 0;
        copyParams.dstY = 0;
        copyParams.dstZ = 0;
        copyParams.dstLOD = 0;

        copyParams.WidthInBytes = (long) dims[0] * Sizeof.FLOAT;
        copyParams.Height = dims[1];
        copyParams.Depth = dims[2];

        JCudaDriver.cuMemcpy3D(copyParams);
    }

    static CUDA_RESOURCE_DESC makeResourceDescriptor(CUarray cuArray) {
        CUDA_RESOURCE_DESC resourceDescriptor = new CUDA_RESOURCE_DESC();
        resourceDescriptor.resType = CUresourcetype.CU_RESOURCE_TYPE_ARRAY;
        resourceDescriptor.array_hArray = cuArray;
        resourceDescriptor.flags = 0;
        return resourceDescriptor;
    }

    static CUDA_TEXTURE_DESC makeTextureDescriptor() {
        CUDA_TEXTURE_DESC textureDescriptor = new CUDA_TEXTURE_DESC();
        textureDescriptor.addressMode = new int[]{
                CUaddress_mode.CU_TR_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP,
                CUaddress_mode.CU_TR_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP,
                CUaddress_mode.CU_TR_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP };
        textureDescriptor.filterMode = CUfilter_mode.CU_TR_FILTER_MODE_LINEAR;
        textureDescriptor.flags = 0;
        textureDescriptor.maxAnisotropy = 1;
        textureDescriptor.mipmapFilterMode = CUfilter_mode.CU_TR_FILTER_MODE_POINT;
        textureDescriptor.mipmapLevelBias = 0;
        textureDescriptor.minMipmapLevelClamp = 0;
        textureDescriptor.maxMipmapLevelClamp = 0;
        return textureDescriptor;
    }

    static CUDA_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC makeResourceViewDescriptor(int[] dims) {
        CUDA_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC resourceViewDescriptor = new CUDA_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC();
        resourceViewDescriptor.format = CUresourceViewFormat.CU_RES_VIEW_FORMAT_FLOAT_1X32;
        resourceViewDescriptor.width = dims[0];
        resourceViewDescriptor.height = dims[1];
        resourceViewDescriptor.depth = dims[2];
        resourceViewDescriptor.firstMipmapLevel = 0;
        resourceViewDescriptor.lastMipmapLevel = 0;
        resourceViewDescriptor.firstLayer = 0;
        resourceViewDescriptor.lastLayer = 0;
        return resourceViewDescriptor;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Marco13: please,add that as an answer

Comment: @talonmies Added. (CC cfuqua: ) Sorry for the hassle. If necessary, I could provide a fixed "snapshot" binary for Win64, but the next release (for CUDA 9.1) should be coming soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this access violation was a bug in JCuda 0.9.0.

The texture handle was erroneously passed to the native function as a `NULL` pointer. This is fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/jcuda/jcuda/commit/c4900ff8c5397b857ffe75a7fffcc6a306f431c9), and the fix will be part of the next release.

A [test case based on the code in the question](https://github.com/jcuda/jcuda/commit/413fe3105d3bd3baca4a45706feff721a8c4d765) has been added.

*Update:* This issue is fixed in [JCuda 0.9.0d](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jcuda/jcuda/0.9.0d).